# How to diagnose SQL Server database spontaneously going into Recovery mode

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a large SQL Server database (approximately 1G) which will spontaneously go into Recovery mode several times per day. This apparently happens only when there are a significant number of transactions happening on the database.

We receive this error: "Database is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished."

The database itself is a log-shipped database, so it is Read-Only. It exists on a fast NetApp storage device, and the SQL Server machine itself has 48 CPUs.

How can I determine what is the cause of the database spontaneously going into Recovery mode?  Can this be caused by excessive IO on the disk array itself?

We've tried setting the AutoClose configuration to Off already.

Answer (score 1):

> > The database itself is a log-shipped database, so it is Read-Only

If this is a log-shipped copy of the database then whenever you are applying the transaction logs on the secondary to be in sync with the primary database then at that time your secondary database will show the above message and this is normal and working as designed.

> > large SQL Server database (approximately 1G)

Thanks for putting that number. Note that 1 GB is NOT at all a big database in these times or did you meant 1 TB?